# jQuery toggle div with multiple select

Tags: jquery

I made the select currency option TH, Eu,USD. If the customer choose THB, the price will show only THB price with multiple price option but when load the page I want the system show default THB price fist when the page load, and then we can change to us or usd later, please advice

```
                  /******************* JQUERY **************************/

          $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#theSelect').change(function(){
    var string = $(this).val();
    $('.hideStuff').slideUp('fast');
    $('.is'+string+'').delay(320).slideDown('fast');
       });
           });


              /****************** CSS **************************/
          .hideStuff {display: none;}​


          /*************** HTML *************************************/

        <div class="selectContainer">
        <select id="theSelect">
        <option value="">- Select -</option>
        <option value="isTHB">THB</option>
        <option value="isUSD">USD</option>
        <option value="isEU">EU</option>
       </select>
       </div>
      <div class="hideStuff isTHB">3000 THB</div>
      <div class="hideStuff isUSD">50 USD</div>
      <div class="hideStuff isEU">40 EU</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you'll probably have to use jQuery Cookie plugin if you want the previously selected values to be stored temporarily (unless you're not getting your values from a $_GET or something) You can then load them from a cookie on page load.

You would implement it onChange:

```
$('#theSelect').change(function(){
   var string = $(this).val();
   $.cookie('currency', string);
....
```

And load when page refreshes

```
$("#theSelect").val($.cookie('currency'));
```

Check out https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 0):

So the only question is, how do you show the THB stuff when the page loads?

```
<div class="selectContainer">
    <select id="theSelect">
        <option value="">- Select -</option>
        <option value="isTHB" selected="selected">THB</option>
        <option value="isUSD">USD</option>
        <option value="isEU">EU</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="hideStuff isTHB" style="display:block;">3000 THB</div>
<div class="hideStuff isUSD">50 USD</div>
<div class="hideStuff isEU">40 EU</div>
```

... looks like you're also adding an unnecessary extra "is" in the last line of your jQuery.

Change `$('.is'+string+'')` to `$('.'+string)`.

Alternatively, if you're wanting the values of your select to be `THB` and not `isTHB` you could take out the preceding "is" and leave it in on your jQuery ( `'.is'+string` ).

Complete code below...

```
/************* HTML *************/
<div class="selectContainer">
        <select id="theSelect">
            <option value="">- Select -</option>
            <option value="THB" selected="selected">THB</option>
            <option value="USD">USD</option>
            <option value="EU">EU</option>
       </select>
</div>

/************* JS *************/
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#theSelect').change(function(){
        var string = $(this).val();
        console.log(string);
        $('.hideStuff').slideUp('fast');
        $('.is'+string).delay(320).slideDown('fast');
    });

});​

/************* CSS *************/
.hideStuff {display: none;}​
```

Comment: NO, I mean show the THB by Default fist  when the page load, and then we can change to us or usd later, please advice.

Comment: That's exactly what I said. :)

Comment: Yes, Thank you so much  I'm so happy Now! :)

Comment: If this provided you with a solution, marking it as "Answered" would be great.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the dropdown to be THB as the default, you should add a selected to the HTML

```
 <select id="theSelect">
        <option value="">- Select -</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="isTHB">THB</option>
        <option value="isUSD">USD</option>
        <option value="isEU">EU</option>
 </select>
```

and then if you want to trigger a change you should add that in your jquery, or if you just want to show it, then just do a show:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#theSelect').change(function(){
        var string = $(this).val();
        $('.hideStuff').slideUp('fast');
        $('.' + string).delay(320).slideDown('fast');
    });

    $('#theSelect').change();

    // or

    $('.isTHB').show();
 });
```